# Dynamics - bungee jumping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, harmonics

A bungee rope is specifically designed and its spring constant is known. The rope is stretched to twice its normal length by a person of mass 75kg hanging at rest from the free end. The length is adjusted according to the weight of the jumper.

For a person of mass m, calculate the depth to which a person would fall if attached to a rope with length l metres.

We have not been taught at all concerning spring constants, so I am basing my work off what I can gather from online.

Currently I have;
$F=kx$ and 
$k=mg/x$ but subbing in $m=75$, $g=9.8$ and $x=l$ still leaves me with l and k as unknowns. Is there any way to get a specific value? or do I just use k in terms of l?

Also, how do I approach calculating the depth to which the jumper falls? Can I use basic projectile motion equations? Or will the acceleration not be constant due to the spring?

Sorry if these questions are dumb, we have been taught absolutely nothing concerning springs so I am guessing at all of this! Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for $k$ is fine as it is. The spring constant will depend on the length of the rope. If this concept is confusing, imagine the rope built out of many small springs. If you cut it in half, you only have half as many springs left. For a given elongation $\Delta x$, each one of the small springs must stretch twice as much now, effectively doubling the spring constant of the rope. Therefore, $k$ is a function of $l$, in just the way you have in your formula.

Solving this with equations of motion is unnecessary complicated, as you would first have to consider free fall until the person has fallen down the length $l$ of the rope, and then solve for the deceleration. As someone else already pointed out, using conservation of energy (therefore of course also neglecting air resistance) is the easiest way to go here. At the bottom the kinetic energy will be zero, so setting $E_\mathrm{grav} = E_\mathrm{spring}$ will give you the maximal elongation of the rope.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the depth to which the person will fall by considering the motion of the person in terms of $\frac{dv}{dx}$ and solving a few differential equations given you know the forces acting on the spring to find the value of $x$ when $v$ is zero, but i think this method would be unnecessarily complicated. A more straightforward method would be by energy considerations, as the elastic potential energy stored in the spring will be $\frac{kx^2}{2}$, and you equate this to the change of gravitational potential energy and kinetic energy.